# Parsing Japanese text from web does not give correct characters

Tags: java, html, rest, tomcat, utf-8

I have a servlet running in Tomcat that take form data input.

When I enter Japanese characters they show up as the string,

ベースにチェ

which is correct, but when I try to parse the string using charAt and substring I get,

```
&#12505;&#12540;&#12473;&#12395;&#12481;&#12455;
```

If I enter the same input in a Java client (swing) then chatAt returns,

ベ ー ス に チ ェ

So, something in going wrong somewhere, but I don't understand utf-8 or unicode much, so I have no idea how to fix it?

The html page is basically,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<form action="ChatServlet" method="post">
<input type="text" name="input">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
```

In the servlet I use,

```
String input = (String)request.getParameter("input");
char next = input.charAt(0);
```

and next == '&' not 'ベ'

but in swing next == 'ベ'

I want 'ベ', not '&'

Comment: http://www.unicode.org/faq/han_cjk.html

Comment: The characters `&#12505;&#12540;&#12473;&#12395;&#12481;&#12455;` correspond to `ベースにチェ`. For some reason you're only seeing three of the characters in the middle. However, the Unicode values are correct.

Comment: this might be a bit hard to tackle without seeing some code/configuration. You said you have a servlet in Tomcat, but what did you exactly use to create the form? How does it exactly pass the string to the server? What do you mean "characters show up as the string", where do they show up? In the console? Etc. ;-)

Comment: Try adding `accept-charset="utf-8"` to the `<form>` tag

Comment: @squeamishossifrage is right: the browser does not know it can send UTF-8 back, and some browsers then create for a high Unicode character such numeric HTML entities `&#<unicode-number>;` (ASCII representation). One may also set the acceptable encodings in the [HTTP response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046505/how-can-i-change-charset-encoding-in-http-response-in-java) of the server.

Comment: Indeed, one *should* set the charset in `Content-Type`, either in the HTTP header or the `<meta>` tag, because `accept-encoding` doesn't work reliably in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally got back to this and figured it out.  There were several issues,
Here is the details, hopefully this will save someone else the fun I had figuring this out.

### Step 1 - Ensure your html/jsp pages are set the UTF-8

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

### Step 2 - Add the following to the top of your jsp pages

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

### Step 3 - In your Servlet doPost or doGet ensure you do the following as the very first line of code (or use a filter)

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
```

This will get thing working, for POST, but GET will still not work.

### Step 4 - In you Tomcat server.config set the URIEncoding

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="9443"
    URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Now everything should work.
I also had another issue in reading data from a rest service.
This is how I fixed it,

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(get.openStream(), "UTF-8");
```

If you don't wrap the stream in a reader with the charset, it will not work.

Hope this helps someone else.