# Java String HTTP encoding

Tags: java, http, encoding

I've got the following method to write HTTP response to browser socket.

```
public static void writeResponse(OutputStream os, HttpResponse response)
        throws IOException {    
    String total = just my http response text;  
    os.write(total.getBytes());
    //os.write(new String(total.getBytes(ISO_8859_1), UTF_8).getBytes()); - my try
    os.flush();
}
```

Charset is `charset=UTF-8`. Content type is `text/plain`.Text output text is

`"Hello-eng\nПривет-rus\nこんにちは-jap\nनमस्ते-hind\nأهلا-arab"`

But my browser can not read anything except English.

> Hello-eng ������-rus ?????-jap ??????-hind ????-arab

What is wrong?

Comment: can you confirm you're using a modern standards compliant and up-to-date browser. Have you tried 2 different browsers. What happens if you show the page source or save it and view with a hex editor?

Comment: Chrome, Opera and Firefox has the same effect. If safe page and open in notepad, I will see English and Russian(!!!), but no others.

Comment: Try ```os.write(total.getBytes(UTF_8));```

Comment: @saka1029, it works. Post as an answer and will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the response string to UTF_8 byte array.  And write it to the response stream.

```
os.write(total.getBytes(UTF_8));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the charset in the http header to match the encoding
[How can i change charset encoding in HTTP response in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046505/how-can-i-change-charset-encoding-in-http-response-in-java)

Comment: But I set it. text/plain;charset=UTF-8